# Style Choice Prompt Hero Card in MS Bot

Tags: css, dialog, styles, prompt, rounded-corners

I have a Bot developed in SDK 4. I am using PromptOptions in Dialog as below :

```
       var options = new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select the services "),
            RetryPrompt = null,
            Style = ListStyle.HeroCard,
            Choices = GetMainMenuChoices(),
        };
```

I need to style the Hero card which as of now is in rectangle shape. Can I make it look like   rounded corner with some color & do some customize style?  Thanks.